# spring test and transaction management

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit4

I'm extremely new to spring testing.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContextTest.xml")
public class joinTest {
@Mock
@Autowired
private AccountDAO DAO;

@Test
public void testMethod()
{
    (DAO).getJoin();
}

}
```

The test complains about the transactionManager that I have in my applicationContextTest. Obviously I'm running this out of a container. I don't really know how to deal with transactions in a Spring Test context.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abstinence.Logic"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://xx.xx.xx.xx/testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="SA"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abstinence.Logic"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key ="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="hibernateDAOOperation" expression="execution(* com.abstinence.Logic.AccountDAO.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="hibernateDAOOperation"/>
</aop:config>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The exact error I get is this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDAO' defined in file [/home/user/NetBeansProjects/WebAbstinenceMaven/target/classes/com/abstinence/Logic/AccountDAO.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txAdvice': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContextTest.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
```

I've been confused for a few days trying to figure this out. Can someone point in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to compatibility problems of Spring with Hibernate 4.3.0.Beta1 and newer reported [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10839).
If this is the problem a downgrade to Hibernate 4.1.7.Final should solve the problem.